# using "with" with qplot (yes it is wrong), unexpected result - really esoteric

Tags: r, ggplot2, environment

Ok, I am taking this class and one of the other students posted a question about plotting using with.  I turns out she didn't need with for the her plots but I got playing around to with with to see how you could use it.

So using with with the base plotting was interesting and I could get cool plots.

Then I decided to try using it with ggplot.  Specifically qplot.  Now I know this isn't the way to do this but I was just curious to see what would happen.

So I did this:

I created a little dataframe - mydf

```
> mydf
    x  y year
1   6 24 2004
2  22 28 2004
3  44 16 2004
4  40 47 2003
5  50 23 2002
6  49 48 2003
7   2 21 2004
8   3 12 2002
9  19 11 2003
10 29 25 2002
```

So the right way to do this is:

```
qplot(x,y,data = mydf)
```

And it works, obviously.  But I was curious to see what happens so I did this

```
with(mydf,qplot(x,y))
```

I didn't really expect it to work but it did.  Cool

So then I tried facets.  So doing it the correct way works.

```
qplot(x,y, facets = .~ year,data = mydf)
```

But this throws an error.

```
> with(mydf,qplot(x,y, facets = .~ year))
Error in FUN("year"[[1L]], ...) : object 'year' not found
```

I find it odd that mydf$x and mydf$y can be accessed by qplot while trying to access year in facets throws an error.

I think this is an environment related issue.  For example I can do this:

```
the_years <- mydf$year
with(mydf,qplot(x,y, facets = .~ the_years))
```

And it plots fine.  So if I have a variable in the global environment it is accessed.

But this

```
with(mydf,qplot(x,y, facets = .~ mydf$year))
Error in FUN(c("mydf", "year")[[2L]], ...) : object 'year' not found
```

throws an error, even though this too is in the global environment.  The error kind of looks like it is splitting up the mydf and year into two different parameters passed to the function.

As I understand it, with creates an environment and then expressions are evaluated within that environment

So this works

```
> with(mydf,{new_years <- year;print(new_years)})
 [1] 2004 2004 2004 2003 2002 2003 2004 2002 2003 2002
Levels: 2002 2003 2004
```

And I was kind of hoping that this would work.  creating a new variable within the with environment.

```
> with(mydf,{new_years <- year; qplot(x,y, facets = .~ new_years)})
Error in FUN("new_years"[[1L]], ...) : object 'new_years' not found
```

But qplot still doesn't see it

So I am hoping that someone smarter than I can tell me what is going on.

I know this is one of the weirdest questions ever.  The correct answer is: "don't do it that way".  :)

I would be perfectly happy if qplot just bombed when I used x and y in that way.  But it just  seems weird that mydf$x and mydf$y are accessible to qplot in the basic plot part.  But mydf$year isn't found in the facets call.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Talking to myself.  Sorry about that, but this was really bugging me.  :)

Here is what I think is going on.  Here is the code from qplot from github.
https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/quick-plot.r

```
if (missing(data)) {
    # If data not explicitly specified, will be pulled from workspace
    data <- data.frame()

    # Faceting variables must be in a data frame, so pull those out
    facetvars <- all.vars(facets)
    facetvars <- facetvars[facetvars != "."]
    names(facetvars) <- facetvars
    facetsdf <- as.data.frame(lapply(facetvars, get))
    if (nrow(facetsdf)) data <- facetsdf
}
```

What I think is happening is that if no data frame is specified then the code tries to grab info from facets.

If no data passed in a data frame is created - called data

facetvars is created from all.vars(facets).

all.vars returns a character vector containing all the names which occur in an expression or call.
http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/all.vars

here are some examples

```
> all.vars(.~ mydf)
[1] "."    "mydf"
> all.vars(.~ mydf$year)
[1] "."    "mydf" "year"
> all.vars(.~ year)
[1] "."    "year"
```

Next line gets rid of the '.'

Then it uses names to set names and then it tries to create a data frame ""getting" information from the environment using the get() function and KABOOM!

Here are the results as I walked through the code

```
> facetvars <- all.vars(.~ year)
> facetvars
[1] "."    "year"
> facetvars <- facetvars[facetvars != "."]
> facetvars
[1] "year"
> names(facetvars) <- facetvars
> facetvars
  year 
"year" 
>  facetsdf <- as.data.frame(lapply(facetvars, get))
Error in FUN("year"[[1L]], ...) : object 'year' not found
```

This is the only place that get is called in the file.  So it is looking in the wrong environment to build the new facetsdf data frame, and there is no way to change the environment - well at least easily.  There is no "year" in the global environment.  "year" does exist in the "with" environment but qplot doesn't look there.

I am not sure what environment qplot is starting in.  I would have thought it would be the with's environment but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Either way, it looks up the environment tree for "year" but never finds it.   "with"'s environment is on another branch.

And here is another example.  Same problem - there is no "year" in any environment that qplot is looking in.

```
> facetvars <- all.vars(.~ mydf$year)
> facetvars
[1] "."    "mydf" "year"
> facetvars <- facetvars[facetvars != "."]
> facetvars
[1] "mydf" "year"
> names(facetvars) <- facetvars
> facetvars
mydf   year 
"mydf" "year" 
>  facetsdf <- as.data.frame(lapply(facetvars, get))
Error in FUN(c("mydf", "year")[[2L]], ...) : object 'year' not found
```

And the example from when it worked

```
> facetvars <- all.vars(.~ the_years)
> facetvars
[1] "."         "the_years"
> facetvars <- facetvars[facetvars != "."]
> facetvars
[1] "the_years"
> names(facetvars) <- facetvars
> facetvars
  the_years 
"the_years" 
>  facetsdf <- as.data.frame(lapply(facetvars, get))
> facetsdf
   the_years
1       2004
2       2004
3       2004
4       2003
5       2002
6       2003
7       2004
8       2002
9       2003
10      2002
```

So now it can find "the_years" in the global environment.  And it can facet on that variable.

Another example.

```
> facetvars <- all.vars(.~ mydf)
> facetvars
[1] "."    "mydf"
> facetvars <- facetvars[facetvars != "."]
> facetvars
[1] "mydf"
> names(facetvars) <- facetvars
> facetvars
  mydf 
"mydf" 
>  facetsdf <- as.data.frame(lapply(facetvars, get))
> facetsdf
   mydf.x mydf.y mydf.year
1       6     24      2004
2      22     28      2004
3      44     16      2004
4      40     47      2003
5      50     23      2002
6      49     48      2003
7       2     21      2004
8       3     12      2002
9      19     11      2003
10     29     25      2002
```

Now this time "mydf" is found - but qplot doesn't know what to do with it.

```
with(mydf,qplot(x,y, facets = . ~ mydf))
Error in layout_base(data, cols, drop = drop) : 
At least one layer must contain all variables used for faceting
```

So, that is my best answer to my own question.  qplot only tries to get() from a different environment when there is no data passed in and, at that point, it tries to use information from facets to create a data frame if facets exists and that is when the code bombs.

***Editing later to add:***
Yes, still talking to myself.  :)  It turns out all you need to do to fix this behavior is make a minor change to the source code for quick-plot.R (the source code for qplot)

all you have to do is move

```
env <- parent.frame()
```

to someplace earlier in the code and then change line 97 in quick-plot.R from

```
facetsdf <- as.data.frame(lapply(facetvars, get))
```

to

```
facetsdf <- as.data.frame(lapply(facetvars, function(x) {get(x,env)}))
```

Then with will work as expected.